# way to mass-add columns in sqlite studio?

Tags: sqlite, csv, sqlitestudio

I'm new to creating databases, and right now all I want to do is import a csv file into an empty sqlite3 database using sqlite studio. I created an extremely basic table with only a single unnamed empty column, and then attempted to import my file into that table; however, I keep getting an error saying that my table has less columns than the file, and any extra columns will be ignored. I'd really like not to have to create 52 dummy columns; is there some kind of way to work around this?

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to use the SQLite Studio interface, not the command line. The documentation for tables is [nonexistent](https://wiki.sqlitestudio.pl/index.php/User_Manual#Creating_and_editing_tables)

Answer (score 1):

Skip table creatioon by yourself. Import into inexisting table and SQLiteStudio will create it for you, with all columns required.